# Single pole or dual pole relay for switching a 3 kW water heater?

Tags: switches, relay, solid-state-relay, home-automation

I have bought a WiFi controlled device to control a 3 kW, 240 V water heater (immersion heater) wirelessly but despite being advertised as 15 A, it actually has a 13 A relay which has "push fit" contacts. I'm not sure I trust it to run for several hours at its maximum rating. I want to replace the relay with a 25 or 30 amp rated relay which will therefore be operating well below it's rated load.

However the original isolator switch to the immersion heater is dual pole. Should I therefore use a dual pole relay behind the isolator switch, or is this not necessary? Is there any advantage of using dual pole in this scenario? Given it's just a resistive load, I'm not sure if there's any particular merit of using a dual-pole relay in this situation?

Comment: Has the WiFi-controlled device a plug? If yes, are plugs polarized in your country?

Comment: 13A * 240V > 3 kW so the existing relay is within ratings for your application. Do you have any evidence that it is untrustworthy at 13A?

Comment: Even though this is likely a home project, many folks would feel uncomfortable answering this due to safety concerns.  Want more input?  Add your location, and be prepared for the phrase "local and regional electric codes".  In general, in the USA, 240V means 2 hot legs.  So if this is your coil disconnect, then for safety, you would want to de-energize both legs with with a 2-pole disconnect.  Please refer to your local and regional electric codes.  In addition, the relay mechanics/contacts are most-stressed during switching.  What's the duty cycle?

Comment: @Janka the heater is hard-wired.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The "evidence" is that similar devices with the same connector type melt when used withing their rating for long periods:  https://community-home-assistant-assets.s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/optimized/3X/a/f/af8e81fd54834eaae87f81b44ef3676a362eb530_2_666x500.jpeg

Comment: @Chris I'm in the UK where our single phase power is 240V, so only one wire needs switching.   The question therefore is if there's any additional advantage in disconnecting the neutral wire when it's off.  I suspect not, as long as I leave the original dual pole isolator switch in front of the circuit to adhere to the dual-pole isolation requirement here.  Duty cycle will be 1-2 hours per night in a warm cupboard (water heater cupboard).

Comment: That counts as evidence... On the question, you need to consider the failure modes and their consequences. What happens if the switch fails ON? Warm water, or a boiler explosion? Dual pole switching will still switch off if one pole welds shut : but if live welds shut it disconnects neutral leaving the circuit at 240V (until you switch the isolator).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm going to use a normal relay (not solid state) which normally fail open.   If it sticks closed somehow, then the thermostat will turn off the water heater at 55C.   If both fail (!)  then the water will eventually boil, but this is a vented cylinder so all that will happen is that there will a lot of noise and steam in my roof space where the vent pipe and overflow tank is.    I'm not going to remove the original switch or thermostat.

Comment: Relay contacts certainly can weld themselves shut. But I think you have that base well covered by other means,

Comment: Internally crossposted [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/193988/single-pole-or-dual-pole-relay-for-switching-a-3kw-water-heater-uk).

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about that component burn-up.  People buy absolute bottom-of-barrel Alibaba crud off the DealExtreme, eBay, BangGood or the Amazon Marketplace junk shop, and then they are stunned - stunned! - when the stuff turns out to be complete rubbish.  And they hook it to AC mains and scary stuff happens.

Answer (score 0):

All new immersion heater thermostats in the UK have a secondary over-heat cutout with a manual reset as a precaution against the primary stat failing.

If the existing stat does not have an overheat cutout it would be wise to replace it with one that does. They're readily available from electrical/plumbing places and in most cases slide into a sleeve in the heater and do not require draining down.

**A single-pole relay will be sufficient.**